# Decoding User Data to String in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, attributeerror

I have a model in Django titled Account

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
```

I am trying to print out the email as a string in views.py.

```
def fill_view(request):

    # ... authentication ...

    email = Account.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()

    # ... setting up forms ....

    can.drawString(10, 100, email)
```

I get the following error:

```
 Exception Type: AttributeError at /fill/
 Exception Value: 'Account' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

How can I decode the email into a string in Django when transferring the data from models.py to views.py?

I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/alpoe2/attributeerror_when_trying_to_retrieve_an_object/) thread on Reddit helpful and it has lead me to believe it might be an issue with mySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an issue with MySQL you are simply not accessing the email from Account object

```
account = Account.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
can.drawString(10, 100, account.email)
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

Do it using a `@property`

```
@property
  def email_text(self):
     return mark_safe(u"%s") % (escape(self.email))
```

You can then call this on any email object that gets saved in `email`. So you would simply have to do `can.drawString(10, 100, email.email_text())`

mark_safe is from django.utils.safestring, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/) on that

Comment: I added your code to my models.py and imported mark_safe and escape. It seems to have successfully altered the property of the data but now I am getting a new error message stating:    'SafeText' object is not callable